# How can I remove keybinding resolver popup on atom

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I miss clicked some keys, and this one turned up. I want to remove this but I don't know how to do it. Please help me...
[I want to remove the pink box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQYB1.jpg)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> that `keybinding resolver` comes up. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> button or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> again. It will remove the popup.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much

Comment: I didn't do that... I really appreciate your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to actually remove it, or perhaps change the keybinding to let it pop up

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, if you press  button that keybinding resolver comes up. Press  button. It will remove the popup.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS platform, the procedure is following:

1. press <kbd>Esc</kbd>
2. press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.